# Twitter search API using jQuery and Ajax - How do I retrieve the data as my demo shows no results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter

I am trying to add a twitter search timeline based on various topics e.g. searching for all the latest tweets on different festivals. I found a tuturial on how to do a general search on different tweets using the twitter API with Jquery and Ajax, but before I can progress further, I do not get any results being displayed when I run the webpage in the browser and trying out different search topics. The code is similar to the tuturial and I am still learning the different twitter APIs to help me with my project, but I think I am still getting confused. Please can someone please look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong. Here is a JSFiddle to demonstrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/YSBtC/ Here is the main source of the javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search').click(function(){
            $('#results').html('');
            console.log($('#i').val());
            var search_term = $('#i').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
                data:{q: search_term},
                success: function(data){
                    $.each(data.results, function(index, tweet){
                        $tweets = $(".tweet").first().clone();
                        console.log(tweet);
                        $tweets.find('.img').attr('src', tweet.profile_image_url)
                        $tweets.find('.name').text(tweet.from_user_name);
                        $tweets.find('.handle').html(twttr.txt.autoLink("@"+tweet.from_user));
                        $tweets.find('.text').html(twttr.txt.autoLink(tweet.text));
                        $tweets.hide().appendTo('#results').delay(400).fadeIn();
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

That because JavaScript crashes on the following lines:

```
$tweets.find('.handle').html(twttr.txt.autoLink("@"+tweet.from_user));
$tweets.find('.text').html(twttr.txt.autoLink(tweet.text));
```

You are trying to access the variable called `twttr` which doesn't exist (at least, not in the code you posted). This is the reason why `#results` div is empty.

Removing those lines (or initializing those variables properly) will solve your problem.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YSBtC/1/

Comment: Hi Akoskm, I have removed the two lines that you said was crashing and when I tested it into the browser it still does not return any results. Please could you advise as for the last 45 mins I had difficulty trying to see the error.

Comment: @JennyP I put a jsfiddle link into my answer, have you tried that one, does it work?

Comment: Hi Akoskm, yes the link you gave me works but when I used the code into my dreamweaver text editor and preview it in the browser, it did not return anything. Do you know why?

Comment: @JennyP If  you fix or remove the above mentioned lines it should work. If it doesn't then it has nothing to do with the script itself but with dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0):

The url in your code has been deprecated in the Twitter API.

The correct url is https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json but needs to be properly authenticated. 
See the API doc for more information https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets